# I have some problems with a value error in python

Tags: python, scipy, valueerror

Here are my codes to plot a stress-strain curve

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText
import pandas as pd


#both strain is a column in the given dataframe, and I manually calculated stress
df_1 = pd.read_csv('1045.csv',skiprows=25,header=[0,1])
print(df_1.head())

A1 = 40.602*(10e-6)
stress1 = ((df_1.Load)/A1)


plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
plt.plot(df_1.Strain1.values,df_1.Load.values,'g')
plt.ylabel('stress(Pa)',fontsize=13)
plt.xlabel('Strain(%)',fontsize=13)
plt.xticks(np.arange(-6e-5,0.15,step=0.005),rotation = 45)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,42000,step=1000))

strain = df_1.Strain1.values
stress = np.array(((df_1.Load.values)/A1))
strain = np.array((df_1.Strain1.values))

LinearLimit=1
Strain_values_linear = np.linspace(strain[0], strain[LinearLimit], num=50, endpoint=True)
Strain_values_eng = np.linspace(strain[LinearLimit], strain[-1], num=50, endpoint=True)
f1 = interp1d(strain, stress, fill_value='extrapolate')
f2 = interp1d(strain, stress, kind=3, fill_value='extrapolate')
```

Now I keep getting a value error saying : "x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis." I don't understand this...i printed the shape of strain and stress and they are the same
Btw here is a screenshot of the csv file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gPle.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are passing an array of shape `(..., N)` as the first argument (meaning `strain` has shape of the form `(..., N)`). SciPy doesn't allow that and throws a `ValueError`. See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) for details. You should run a for loop if you have multiple vectors in `strain` array. The following code should work, considering you want to interpolate 1 function for each row in `strain` (and that strain is a 2-d array. If it isn't, you can easily convert it using `strain.reshape(-1, N)`):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText
import pandas as pd


#both strain is a column in the given dataframe, and I manually calculated stress
df_1 = pd.read_csv('1045.csv',skiprows=25,header=[0,1])
print(df_1.head())

A1 = 40.602*(10e-6)
stress1 = ((df_1.Load)/A1)


plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
plt.plot(df_1.Strain1.values,df_1.Load.values,'g')
plt.ylabel('stress(Pa)',fontsize=13)
plt.xlabel('Strain(%)',fontsize=13)
plt.xticks(np.arange(-6e-5,0.15,step=0.005),rotation = 45)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,42000,step=1000))

strain = df_1.Strain1.values
stress = np.array(((df_1.Load.values)/A1))
strain = np.array((df_1.Strain1.values))

LinearLimit=1
Strain_values_linear = np.linspace(strain[0], strain[LinearLimit], num=50, endpoint=True)
Strain_values_eng = np.linspace(strain[LinearLimit], strain[-1], num=50, endpoint=True)

f1, f2 = [], []
for row in range(len(strain)):
    f1.append(interp1d(strain[row], stress, fill_value='extrapolate'))
    f2.append(interp1d(strain[row], stress, kind=3, fill_value='extrapolate'))
```

Edit: From the comment, you have `strain` array of shape `(222, 1)`. This means you already have a vector but the shape is not compatible with what SciPy accepts. In this case, you will have to reshape the strain and sress array to have the shape of the form `(N,)`. Following code should work:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText
import pandas as pd


#both strain is a column in the given dataframe, and I manually calculated stress
df_1 = pd.read_csv('1045.csv',skiprows=25,header=[0,1])
print(df_1.head())

A1 = 40.602*(10e-6)
stress1 = ((df_1.Load)/A1)


plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
plt.plot(df_1.Strain1.values,df_1.Load.values,'g')
plt.ylabel('stress(Pa)',fontsize=13)
plt.xlabel('Strain(%)',fontsize=13)
plt.xticks(np.arange(-6e-5,0.15,step=0.005),rotation = 45)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,42000,step=1000))

strain = df_1.Strain1.values
stress = np.array(((df_1.Load.values)/A1))
strain = np.array((df_1.Strain1.values))
strain = strain.reshape(-1,)
stress = stress.reshape(-1,)

LinearLimit=1
Strain_values_linear = np.linspace(strain[0], strain[LinearLimit], num=50, endpoint=True)
Strain_values_eng = np.linspace(strain[LinearLimit], strain[-1], num=50, endpoint=True)
f1 = interp1d(strain, stress, fill_value='extrapolate')
f2 = interp1d(strain, stress, kind=3, fill_value='extrapolate')
```

Comment: I printed the shape of the strain and stress arrays, they are both (222,1).
i tried using the for look you've provided above ,but I get another error here:
ValueError: x and y arrays must have at least 2 entries. I can't figure out what this means

Comment: I added a screenshot of my csv file above

Comment: You already have a vector so no need to run the for loop. You will have to reshape your ``strain`` array to shape ``(222,)`` using ``strain = strain.reshape(-1,)``. Everything else ceteris paribus. I will update the answer accordingly.